# transform-origin not working properly with SVG in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, transform

While creating a [CSS-animated menu burger button](http://codepen.io/rijk/pen/Ltxov) I stumbled upon an oddity in Firefox.

See this CodePen for an example: http://codepen.io/rijk/pen/vfmHa. In Chrome it works as expected; when hovering over the line it rotates 45 degrees downward, from the right corner, as defined in the CSS:

```
line {
  transform-origin: right center;
}

svg:hover line {
  transform: rotate( -45deg );
}
```

But in Firefox, it seems to ignore the `transform-origin` property altogether! Even though it's visibly active in the developer tools, modifying its value (to `left` for instance) seems to do nothing.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in Firefox?

Comment: Ha, I've been having the same issue. Compare the second to last animation of the following link in Chrome and Firefox: http://dev.redlegg.juiceinteractive.com/about/process

Comment: It appears to be related to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923193